# How do I justify this technically?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I have two differentiable functions, $\mathrm{f}$ and $\mathrm{F}$, with the properties $\mathrm{F}(0)=0$ and
$$\frac{\mathrm{dF}}{\mathrm{d}x} = \mathrm{f}(x)$$
Applying the fundamental theorem of calculus gives:
$$F(x) = \int_0^x \mathrm{f}(t) \ \mathrm{d}t$$
Now, consider the following differential equation, with the initial conditions $y=1$ when $x=0$:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}+\mathrm{f}(x)\,y=0$$
This equation is seperable and we obtain:
$$\int\frac{1}{y}\mathrm{d}y =- \int\mathrm{f}(x)\ \mathrm{d}x$$
I need to write this equation in terms of $\mathrm{F}$, so I need to introduce some limits. When $x=0$ we have $y=1$ and when $x=x$ we have $y=y(x)$ and so I feel that I can introduce the limits
$$\int_1^y\frac{1}{\gamma}\mathrm{d}\gamma =- \int_0^x\mathrm{f}(\chi)\ \mathrm{d}\chi $$

**How can I technically justify this last step?**

**EDIT**: I would like to know how to go from the ODE to the final line. One part of this is to justify expressing one integral w.r.t. one variable and with one set of limits in terms of another limit w.r.t. another variable and with different limits. I suspect that a single integration and a cunning substitution would do the trick.

Comment: Is the last line the final goal or do you wish to reach further? If  you do, what is the goal?

Comment: @GitGud I don't need to go any further. In formally, I need to technically justify "separating variables with limits".

Comment: I don't really get some of your steps because of the abuse of notation, but if in the last line one can read $y$ as $y(x)$, then you can justify the equality by differentiating both sides with respect to $x$.

Comment: @GitGud This abuse of notation is quite standard when solving ODEs. It's exactly analogous to saying that:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}\cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d}x}$$

Another place that this abuse of notation appears is

$$\int_{x_1}^{x_2} y \ \mathrm{d}x = \int_{t_1}^{t_2} y \ \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} \ \mathrm{d}t$$

My question has been answered. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you divide your differential equation by $y$, it becomes
$$
(\ln(y))^\prime+f=0.
$$
Integrating both sides from $0$ to $x$, this becomes
$$
\int_{0}^x(\ln(y))^\prime(s)\,ds=-\int_0^xf(\chi)\,d\chi.
$$
Now the change-of-variables formula can be applied to the integral on the LHS, giving
$$
\int_{y(0)}^{y(x)}\frac{1}{\gamma}\,d\gamma=-\int_0^x f(\chi)\,d\chi.
$$

edit: Here is a little more explanation of the change-of-variable formula and its application to this problem. Suppose we have a smooth function $u:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ whose derivative is nowhere zero. The non-vanishing derivative assumption implies that there is an inverse function $u^{-1}$ whose domain is the image of $[a,b]$ under $u$, i.e. $[\min(u(a),u(b)),\max(u(a),u(b))]$. For simplicity, assume $u^\prime$ is positive and that $u^{-1}$ is smooth.

Now consider the integral
$$
I_1(b)=\int_a^bg(s)\,ds.
$$ 
Let
$$
I_2(b)=\int_{u(a)}^{u(b)}g(u^{-1}(r))(u^{-1})^\prime(r)\,dr=\int_{u(a)}^{u(b)}g(u^{-1}(r))\frac{1}{u^\prime(u^{-1}(r))}\,dr.
$$
I claim $I_1(b)=I_2(b)$. In order to see this, first check that $I_1^\prime(b)=I_2^\prime(b)$. By the chain rule and the fundamental theorem of calculus,
$$
I_2^\prime(b)=(u^\prime(b))\left(g(u^{-1}(u(b)))\frac{1}{u^\prime(u^{-1}(u(b)))}\right)=g(b).
$$ 
By the fundamental theorem of calculus (again), 
$$
I_1^\prime(b)=g(b).
$$
So everything checks out with the equality $I_1^\prime(b)=I_2^\prime(b)$. But now we see that 
\begin{align}
(I_1+I_2)^\prime=0,
\end{align}
which implies that $I_1(b)=I_2(b)+c$, where $c$ is a constant that does not depend on $b$. Moreover, $c$ must be zero because $I_1(a)=I_2(a)=0$. This proves my claim that
$$
\int_a^bg(s)\,ds=\int_{u(a)}^{u(b)}g(u^{-1}(r))(u^{-1})^\prime(r)\,dr=\int_{u(a)}^{u(b)}g(u^{-1}(r))\frac{1}{u^\prime(u^{-1}(r))}\,dr.
$$

Here is how this can all be applied to the integral
$$
\int_0^x (\ln(y))^\prime(s)\,ds.
$$
Assume that $y$ has a non-zero derivative on the interval $[0,x]$. In the above formula, set $g=(\ln(y))^\prime$ and $u=y$. We have
$$
\int_0^x (\ln(y))^\prime(s)\,ds=\int_{y(0)}^{y(x)}(\ln y)^\prime(y^{-1}(r))\frac{1}{y^\prime(y^{-1}(r))}\,dr=\int_{y(0)}^{y(x)}\frac{1}{r}\,dr.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You don't actually answer my question. The "change of coordinate formula" is exactly what I want justifying. How do you go get

$$\int_0^x \left( \ln y\right)'(s) \ \mathrm{d}s = \int_{y(0)}^{y(x)} \frac{1}{\gamma} \ \mathrm{d}\gamma$$

Comment: @FlybyNight I edited my answer to include a justification and statement of the change-of-variables formula.

Comment: Hi Josh. Thanks for that. So, in short, we can get

$$\int_0^x \frac{1}{y}\cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}s}\cdot\mathrm{d}s = \int_{y(0)}^{y(s)} \frac{1}{r}\cdot\mathrm{d}r$$
by using the substitution $r=y(s)$. That's perfect. Thank you!